# configuring google cloud datastore in django project

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I don't know how to configure google cloud datastore with Django app. I went through a tutorial that sets database backends to dummy as follows

```
    DATABASES = {
     'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
     }
    }
```

But in this way my database is not properly configured. I don't understand the logic behind dummy. My admin panel is not accessed either. So my question is how to properly configure cloud datastore with django app. Complete configuration will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Django is best designed for relational databases, but Cloud Datastore is non-relational, so it is not easy to use with Django. [django-nonrel](http://django-nonrel.org/) and [Djangae](https://djangae.org/) are attempts to make this task possible, but they are not well supported.

Instead of that, you might want to use [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/) which is a relational database like Django expects. You can then access it like any other MySQL or PostgreSQL database.

There is more information on using [Django on GCP here](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/)